# MS Word 2010 mailmerge in Delphi 5

Tags: delphi, ms-word, mailmerge

could anyone help?

I've inherited some software written in Delphi 5 which allows member data and fields from a database (.ADT file) to be used merged in to word.

It works fine with all version of Word except 2010 where it won't load any documents and shows the error:

"That Method is not available on that object"

I have been told the solution is to replace the preset components OpWord and OpDataSet with Ole variants. I have done so with OpWord using:

wrdApp := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');

and the documents now load up but without any merge field data. Can anyone let me know how to extract this data from the database, as the OpDataSet seems to simply just point at the table?

Or can anyone suggest a better solution than the one I'm trying. I'm very new to Delphi so I'm in abit over my head

**Edit:** (Requested Info)

Sorry I have more details and code if required.

The components appear to belong to a library called OfficePartner along with TOpExcel,TOpOutlook and others.

The .doc is selected from a popup ListPane on Form30, opened and populated with merge field data from Table 4. Table 1 is the members database:

```
  {Use Table4 as we can Set a range on it}
  Table4.SetRange([Table1.FieldByName('Member Id').AsString],[Table1.FieldByName('Member Id').AsString]);

  {Open Word}
  OpWord1.Connected := True;

  {Open the Test Document}
  OpWord1.OpenDocument(DocumentDirectory + '\' + Form30.ListBox1.Items[Form30.ListBox1.ItemIndex]);

  {Populate the Test Document}
  OpWord1.ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OfficeModel := OpDataSetModel1;
  OpWord1.ActiveDocument.PopulateMailMerge;
  OpWord1.ActiveDocument.ExecuteMailMerge;
```

I hope this helps...

Comment: Without some code and a better indication of where/which library OpWord and OpDataSet are coming from (they certainly are not standard Delphi 5 components), it's anybody's guess. Show how you create the various COM objects (not just the word app) and how you open the document and/or start the merge.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. Apologies I didn't want to write such a long question but I've included some code in the edit above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little procedure for word mail merge that I used way back for D6, it's a just snippet and you have to include in some class, I don't have Delphi anymore so can't compile to make sure that it works, anyway here it is, hope it helps:

```
procedure MailMergeWord;
var
  WordApp: TWordApplication;
  WordDoc: TWordDocument;
  doc : WordDocument;
  FileName: OleVariant;
  xx: integer;
begin
  WordApp := TWordApplication.Create(nil);
  WordApp.ConnectKind := ckNewInstance;
  WordDoc := TWordDocument.Create(WordApp);
  FileName := 'TemplateDoc.doc';

  doc := WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam
                                 ,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam
                                 ,EmptyParam);

  WordDoc.ConnectTo(Doc);
  for xx := 1 to WordDoc.Fields.Count do
    WordDoc.Fields.Item(xx).Result.Text := OnWordVariable(WordDoc.Fields.Item(xx).Code.Text);
  WordDoc.PrintOut;
  WordDoc.Free;
  WordApp.Free;
end;


function OnWordVariable(varName: string): string;
begin
  Result := 'Value based on variable name';
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. My understanding of objects and their attributes continues to fail me though and I can't see how your field data is in the WordDoc.Fields and is passed in to the template.
At the minute I'm trying to create a DataSourceFile in to which I'll pass the data from the table but I'm getting mixed up with StringLists. argh

Comment: I am not sure that I understand you but, OnWordVariable function is called for all fields defined in word document "TemplateDoc.doc" and OnWordVariable function is just an example, you have to provide your own logic to fill fields in word doc according to field names defined in word doc. Don't see why you are doing this DataSourceFile, let's assume that your table had field names same as fields in word, so you can simple do this : Result := table.FieldByName("varName").AsString;

Comment: Fantastic! thanks antonio... My clients template wordvariables actually do not actually match the field names in the table so I will either have to remove the extra underscores or make new templates. If this works I will have just one more question - When my clients creates their own templates & opens up a blank word document, how can I feed in merge fields options. I avhieved this through the sourcefile technique i copied from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/229310, but is there a simpler way using the wrdDoc.Merge.Fields? thanks alot

Comment: sorry notidaho, but I don't know, I always user predefined templates, maybe ask another question and somebody would probably know

Comment: I'll figure that part out thanks. One more problem though - I'm getting the error: "Table4: Field 'MERGEFIELD "Member ID"' not found." It's trying to search for the varName with "MERGEFIELD" attached to the front. I can try do String Delete but did this happen for you? Maybe it's a Word2010 thing...

Comment: OK I just read that {MERGEFIELD "varName"} means it's displaying fieldcodes not fieldresults... however when I remove the << and >> ascii from eitherside the string I get the error "Variant does not reference an automation object" but when I StringRemove the MERGEFIELD from the fieldcodes it's works, but I get an error "Method 'Items' not supported by automation object". What a mess

Comment: To conclude I used StringRemove on the fieldcodes, the error was due an incorrected method I was using to close the documents. Thank you very much for your code and help Antonio :)