# Delphi MailMerge Word2010 new page command

Tags: delphi, ms-office, mailmerge, word-2010

I am trying to update my membership software written in Delphi, to mailmerge in to Word2010.

I'm using

```
wrdApp := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
wrdDoc := wrdApp.Documents.add();
```

then for each merge field name in a template I'm replacing it with the corresponding field value from a table.

I have successfully done this for single members thanks to a previous answer: [MS Word 2010 mailmerge in Delphi 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572621/ms-word-2010-mailmerge-in-delphi-5/6580756#6580756)

However I'm having trouble iterating this code for all members in the table. Ideally I need the template to appear on a new page in the same document with the next members details on.

Currently I can only overwrite the same document for each member, or create a new document each time.

Can anyone advise me how to either recreate the template on the next page, merge multiple documents in to the same one or suggest an alternative method.

many thanks

Comment: `Windows.Application` should probably be `Word.Application`.

Comment: yea typo on OP sorry, question still valid. Cannot infact open multiple documents as it seems the same template .doc can't be opened multiple times. I thought about pasting the content of the template multiple times in to the same new document but it would be hard to populate each iteration with different details. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually creating a mailmerge.

Here's some code (see note below) that might help. It's using Delphi's `TWordApplication` component to handle the connection and provide the datatypes, but it should give you a direction to go in:

```
// Drop a TWordApplication (from the Servers palette page) on a new blank form,
// and change it's name to WordApp. No other property changes or components are
// used.

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Doc: _Document;
  DBName: string;
  Pause, SQL, Connection, SaveChanges: OleVariant;
begin
  WordApp.Connect;
  Doc := WordApp.Documents.AddOld(EmptyParam, EmptyParam);
  WordApp.Visible := True;

  SetUpMergeDoc(Doc);
  DBName := 'YourDatabasePath\DatabaseName';
  Connection := 'YourADOorODBCConnectionString';
  SQL := 'SELECT * FROM customer';
  Doc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource(DBName, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam,
                               EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam,
                               EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, Connection,
                               SQL, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam);
  // Do the actual mailmerge.
  Pause := False;
  Doc.MailMerge.Destination := wdSendToNewDocument;
  Doc.MailMerge.Datasource.FirstRecord := wdDefaultFirstRecord;
  Doc.MailMerge.Datasource.LastRecord := integer(wdDefaultLastRecord);
  Doc.MailMerge.Execute(Pause);

  // Save the mailmerged document
  SaveChanges := wdDoNotSaveChanges;
  WordApp.Quit(SaveChanges, EmptyParam, EmptyParam);
  Doc := nil;
  WordApp := nil;
end;

procedure TForm1.SetUpMergeDoc(Doc: _Document);
var
  R: Range;
  Direction: OleVariant;
begin
  R := Doc.Range(EmptyParam, EmptyParam);

  Direction := wdCollapseEnd;
  R.InsertAfter('Dear ');
  R.Collapse(Direction);

  { Insert a field with the name of the datasource field }
  Doc.MailMerge.Fields.Add(R, 'Company');
  R := Doc.Range(EmptyParam, EmptyParam);
  R.Collapse(Direction);
  R.InsertParagraphAfter;
  R.InsertAfter('We have yet to receive payment for our invoice of ');
  R.Collapse(Direction);
  Doc.MailMerge.Fields.Add(R, 'LastInvoiceDate');
  R := Doc.Range(EmptyParam, EmptyParam);
  R.Collapse(Direction);
  R.InsertAfter('.');
  R.InsertParagraphAfter;
  R.InsertAfter('Cough up or we''ll send the boys round.');
  R.InsertParagraphAfter;
end;
```

NOTE: Much of this code was obtained from a downloaded [example](http://www.djpate.freeserve.co.uk/UsingWordMMerge.zip) I got from the [Word automation](http://www.djpate.freeserve.co.uk/AutoWord.htm) page of Deborah Pate's [website](http://www.djpate.freeserve.co.uk/). (Deborah was (and may still be) a member of TeamB.) I simply modified it to connect via `TWordApplication` and updated it to compile under Delphi XE.

As I said, it's using `TWordApplication` to make the connection to Word and expose the methods and types used. Everything else is done in the code itself.

Comment: Thanks for the code Ken, the reason why I'm using search/replace is because my software uses Advantage Database Tables, which it connects to using TAdsTable & TAdsConnection from an Advantage dataset I downloaded. I'm not sure if they'r compatible with the above code, what would I put for connectionstring? 
The method I'm replacing used TOpWord and TOpDatasetModel, which connects to the ADS table, however described in my previous post, with Word2010 it throws up the error "method not available on that object"

Comment: Coincidentally I just entered the DB Name as my Members.ADT location, and left connection blank. The table is opened as read-only as it's data-locked, and the field/record delimiters don't work

Comment: I' m not sure; I've never tried this using ADS. Have you looked at the Advantage ODBC driver (free from their website) for the data connection?

Comment: I'm having the most success creating a mergedatafile as per the MS Support Page, populating the file with a function which grabs all the fields for each member, then executing the merge.
The only downside I can see is that I have around 45 field names/values to manually list in the code. Best I can do unless I figure out a way to grab merge fields from Advantage Tables... thanks

Comment: just ran in to trouble - maximum of 255 chars allowed in the HeaderRecord String... my field names total 580 chars...

Comment: You're using enough columns in a **mailmerge** to exceed the 255 char limit? Are you sure a Word mailmerge is the right solution for what you need to do? There are other (and often better) reporting solutions than a Word document.

Comment: I have about 50 fields yeah... excessive I know. I've cut it down to about 25 commonly used ones but I can foresee a client calling saying where has my "Sortcode" field gone?! CreateDataDource() won't accept a stringlist parameter and variant types gives the error "variant does not relate to automation object". If I need more fields I may have to find out how to link to ADS another way...

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not really performing a mailmerge but fore of a search and replace. Is there a reason for this? Otherwise why not just set up a 'real' mailmerge which would solve your problems.

Comment: As described in my previous post*, the current real mailmerge with OpWord & OpDataSetModel and TAdsTable doesn't work with Word 2010.
I need an alternative which works with Advantage Tables.
*http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572621/ms-word-2010-mailmerge-in-delphi-5